# Assignin field of a structure instead another structure

Tags: matlab, structure

I'm trying to modify fields (that is in the base workspace) of a structure from inside a function. Hence, I'm trying to use the `assignin` function.

```
assignin('base', 'arg', setfield('arg.aa','abc', 60))
```

My structure is as follow :

```
arg = struct('aa', struct('abc',30));
```

Hence, I'm trying to modifiy the field `abc`. However, the `assignin` command line I'm using is overwriting the structure `aa` and put the field `abc`.

So after the `assignin`, `aa` is gone and I'm left with `arg.abc = 60`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
assignin('base', 'arg', setfield('arg.aa','abc', 60))
```

This is not doing what you want, I presume.
This call first evaluates `setfield('arg.aa','abc', 60)` in the local/function workspace and only then assigns the result to the base workspace. Wich results in a struct with the single field `abc` having the value `60`, since the first `setfield` argument is a string.
(That should be raising a warning btw.)

You could replace this by:

```
evalin('base', 'arg.aa = setfield(arg.aa, ''abc'', 60);')
```

or, easier to read while doing the same:

```
evalin('base', 'arg.aa.abc = 60;')
```